# Linking files to be found by PHP server

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, webserver, symbolic-link

What is the correct way to link local directory `~/dir` to `/path/dir`, so that the PHP server looking for `/path/dir/file.php` will find `~/dir/file.php`?

In my concrete situation
I am running XAMPP PHP server on Mac getting the following errors:

```
Warning: include_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms/tms.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/dmitrizaitsev/Sites/newsite/index.php on line 2

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms/tms.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Users/dmitrizaitsev/Sites/newsite/index.php on line 2
```

So PHP is looking for the file:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms/tms.php
```

Which I am trying to link to my local directory

```
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/Sites/newsite/tms
```

…which contains the file `tms.php`.

I have tried to

```
sudo ln -s ~/Sites/newsite/tms /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/

ls -lisa /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms
26232130 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  38 26 Apr 16:30 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms -> /Users/dmitrizaitsev/Sites/newsite/tms
```

but it doesn't seem to work with PHP
and doesn't list the files:

```
|system| Dmitris-MacBook-Pro in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
○ → ls -lisa /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms/
ls: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tms/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: do you have FollowSymLinks on? does php have permission to access all the dirs (both the path up to htdocs, and tms and children)?

Comment: Where can I check for these settings?

Comment: permissions are as simple as `ls -l path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2`, as for the conf, XAMPP doesn't seem to have any documentation so I couldn't say unless you give me a listing of the files under `/Applications/XAMPP/`, `ls -lR` should do.

Comment: I mean whether php has right permissions?

Comment: According to this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46062/change-the-user-apache-runs-as XAMPP runs as the "nobody" user by default, which means you need to grant permission to everyone/world (the right-most permission digit) to read the files and execute the directories involved.